# Difference between Masked Autoencoder and Masked Augmentation

Tags: autoencoders, data-augmentation

Is there any difference between using a masked autoencoder and applying masked augmentation (as proposed in the Hide and Seek Paper) when training a regular autoencoder?

Follow up: Any issue with using masked augmentation with CNNs as opposed to ViT?